# How do I return the results of this function?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I return steps from this HealthKit Query? 
I get error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call. Code:

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var steps = Double()
    var date = NSDate()
    var query = performHKQuery()  -->error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    performHKQuery()
    printsteps()
}

func performHKQuery () -> (steps: Double, date: NSDate){
    let healthKitManager = HealthKitManager.sharedInstance
    let stepsSample = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount)
    let stepsUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()

    let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(
        sampleType: stepsSample,
        predicate: nil,
        limit: 0,
        sortDescriptors: nil)
        {
            (sampleQuery, samples, error) in

            for sample in samples as [HKQuantitySample]
            {
                self.steps  = sample.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(stepsUnit)
                self.date  = sample.startDate
            }
    }
    healthKitManager.healthStore.executeQuery(sampleQuery)
    return (steps, date)
}

func printsteps() {

     println(query.steps)           -->error: ViewController does not have a member named query
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! If you can also please explain why your solution works then that would be great! Thanks

Code has been updated after feedback from @jrturton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HKQuery` is the name of a class, and you're using it as a variable name. This is confusing the compiler.

Change the name to `query` or something instead.

You also have some structural problems:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var steps = Double()
    var date = NSDate()
    var HKQuery = performHKQuery()  -->error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

Here you're declaring a property and initialising it straight away. You can't use this as an initializer since `self`, that owns the method, doesn't exist at initialization.

Change the declaration to:

```
var query : (steps: Double,date: NSDate)?
```

This sets it as an optional tuple type. In viewDidLoad, you do this:

```
query = performHKQuery()
```

To set the value.

Then, in `printSteps`, do this:

```
func printsteps() {

    println(query?.steps)
}
```

Comment: Which error, the missing argument or the expected declaration?

Comment: error: Missing argument is still there
error: Expected declaration changed to ViewController does not have a member named query. I guess the second error goes away once I sort out the first..

Comment: OK, I looked at it not on my phone and noticed some more problems. Answer  updated.